# How do I get focussed images with my T-adaptor and 6mm eyepeice?

Tags: photography

I have a Celestron 5se + canon 650d. They are mated with the celestron t-ring and the 93625 t-adaptor. [image: picture below]

I want to take magnified photos of planets with the camera. But if I add an eyepiece to the t-adaptor, everything gets blur.

Here are some scenarios that highlight the problem:

1. look at Jupiter with 25mm eyepiece in telescope: clear and focused image
2. look at Jupiter with 6mm eyepiece in telescope: clear and focused zoomed image
3. look at Jupiter with camera and no eyepiece inside the t-adaptor, in telescope: clear and focused image but small.
4. look at Jupiter with camera and 6mm eyepiece inside the t-adaptor, in telescope: large unfocused ball

I dont know how to solve this.

Clearly, the 93625 t-adaptor was made to accept an eyepiece and lock it with the thumbscrew, but why does it not result in focused images?

Comment: This may have been more on topic at [Photography SE](http://photo.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the eyepiece, and no camera lens, is a very different configuration to the camera+tube+scope (case 3).  The configuration you're after is "Eyepiece projection".

I don't know exactly what you have available, but I believe you will need to fit a T-threaded extension tube to the external thread on your T-adapter. Then fit the camera onto that.

Note - before you go out and buy a new extension you can probably do a hand-held test of this by the following:

- Attach the adapter to the scope, with a low-power eyepiece in the adapter (low power makes the test easier to see.)
- Point the scope at anything distant (you can do this in daylight, but NOT at the sun of course!)
- Now hold the camera, by hand, a few inches behind the
  eyepiece+adapter. Perhaps you can use a cardboard tube to keep the stray light out.
- See if you can adjust the scope's focus, and the camera position, to get a sharp image.

If this worked, then you can get a T-threaded extension tube to go on the back of your current adapter, to hold the camera in position.

See for example this link:
http://www.astronomysource.com/2011/10/13/eyepiece-projection/

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a shot with a manual check of distance from the lens to the sensor. Hopefully making it further away will get it crisp. I dont know how these telescope makers justify these crazy prices for what is essentially an empty pipe.